# How to install newrelic in kibana

Tags: node.js, kibana, newrelic, hapi.js

I'm trying to install newrelic for my kibana instance. I'm getting data in newrelic but receiving the following warning:

`Some modules were uninstrumented during the current time window: bluebird, hapi. Make sure require('newrelic'); is the first line of the application's main module.`

I thought [this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/server/kbn_server.js) was the "application's main module", but apparently not. Where should I place `require('newrelic');` in the kibana code to get it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct location to place `require('newrelic');` is the [cli/index.js](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/cli/index.js) file which is called by the kibana run script. It took some time for the warning message to go away in the newrelic UI.